# Checking if static ip is assigned correctly

Tags: macos, networking, ip

I am checking if the static IP assigned to me works correctly.When i ping the ip from the machine itself it works.However if i go to the web and check my IP it is something different .I am not sure why the two different answers.

Comment: Is your static IP address **supposed** to be a public IP address?  It's not that clear from your question.

Comment: I guess probably not .This is a company machine i am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a public IP address (if it starts with 192.168, or 10., [there are some other private ranges] it is private) you won't see it from the public Web.  The web will see your address as the address of the NAT box through which you access the Web.

Comment: it starts with 172. Is that a private address too?

Comment: 172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x is a private range